# How should one use an hour string that can be "24" with datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

When I try to do the following

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("2824", "%d%H")
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 510, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 346, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 4
```

As far as I can see, this is because of using "24" as an hour instead of "00". Ultimately my code is like the following:

```
tmp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%d%H")

now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

start_datetime = datetime.datetime(
                     now.year,
                     now.month,
                     tmp.day,
                     tmp.hour,
                     tmp.minute
                 )
```

Here, the variable `timestamp` is a string of the form DDHH, where DD is the date and HH is the hour and HH can take the value "24". How should I address this nontrivial problem?

Comment: Where does this kind of date come from?

Comment: Does 24 mean the _same_ as 00 (i.e. beginning of the day given), or does it mean _00_ the following day? (as is tradition in Japanese IIRC).

Comment: @BillBell This arises in a TAF (terminal aerodrome forecast) string, such as the following: `TAF EGPF 281657Z 2818/2918 15008KT 9999 FEW035 PROB40 TEMPO 2818/2824 9000 RA TEMPO 2900/2908 7000 RA PROB40 TEMPO 2902/2908 BKN012 BECMG 2907/2910 23012KT PROB30 TEMPO 2912/2918 8000 SHRA`. A string like "2818/2824" in a TAF is a time window during which a forecast is valid, where the start of the time window is 18:00 on the 29th and the end of the time window is 24:00 on the 28th.

Comment: @MatsLindh See my immediately previous comment. The "24" is the last moment of a specified date, or logically the first hour of the next date.

Comment: `strptime` won't accept any hour greater than 23 for `%H`. I'd pre-process the string before giving it to this function.

Comment: These have to be treated like odometer readings. The question is, how? By that I mean to say, if the day clicks over on 31 March then it must change to 01.

Comment: I think you might also have a second problem: you assume that all the dates are in the current month, but I think TAF dates are in the future within one month of the present date.  In other words, 0223 would mean 23:00 on October 2, not 23:00 on September 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

ONE_DAY = timedelta(days=1)

def parse_time(s):
    if s.endswith("24"):
        s = s[:-2] + "00"    
        return datetime.strptime(s, "%d%H") + ONE_DAY

tmp = parse_time("2824")

now = datetime.utcnow()

start_datetime = datetime(
                     now.year,
                     now.month,
                     tmp.day,
                     tmp.hour,
                     tmp.minute
                 )
print(start_datetime)

>>> 
2017-09-29 00:00:00
>>>
```